# VeeValidate 3.1 not showing errors

Tags: vee-validate

Using VeeValidate for the first time and things "look" correct but I am not getting any feedback from the errors. Following the documentation I have implemented the `ValidationProvider` around my input.

```
<ValidationProvider
    v-if="!coinbaseKeys.existing"
    v-slot="{ errors }"
    rules="required|alphaNum"
    >

    <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    <input>type="text" class="form-control"></input>

</ValidationProvider>
```

I have also created some rules of my own inside a `validation.js` file.

```
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import {
  required,
  email,
  alpha_num,
  length
} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

extend('email', email);
extend('required', required);
extend('alpha_num', alpha_num);
extend('length', length);
```

I am not getting any console errors, but when I type in this field there are no errors showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I had no `v-model` on the `input` very...very rookie mistake. VeeValidator doesn't know where the data to validate is if there is no v-model. I wish VeeValidator would make an error show in this circumstance.

Comment: File a bug on github, that's a great idea!